# Videoplayer entering fullscren in Chrome Android stops streaming

Tags: java, google-chrome, video-streaming, plyr.js, android-chrome

Ok, this is an issue I've had since I started working on my project a year ago. When entering fullscreen on Chrome on Android(only Android) my Plyr.io videoplayer stops streaming and enters an infinite loading phase (Only happens like 50% of the times I enter full screen).

Although this Issue can easily be fixed by clicking somewhere on the progress bar(setting another time) or reloading. I've noticed it also happens on the other websites with video streaming.

I use Plyr.io for Videoplayer and https://gist.github.com/chikien276/66229316147ba1180df2f84caff8730d as multipart filesender from a spring boot server.

Is this a known issue? how can it be fixed? Is this a server or client side problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain but it sounds like a client side issue. I believe it can be fixed by rewinding your video by a second when the fullscreen switch happens.

```
function onFullScreen(e) {
  var isFullscreenNow = document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null
  // rewind your video here or add a setTimeout for 1 second and then seek the video.
}

document.getElementById("video").addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', onFullScreen)
```

your video will anyway not play for a little while when switching. Maybe this hack can solve your problem